# I got a problem cleaning a str series that is inside a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I got a DataFrame from a dictionary. I have to clean the data, so I define a process that eliminate :@_/ and all:

I found that I can do this in order to clean my data (It's seems all the cells are list into the DataFrame)

```
data.Abstract.iloc[0]=pre_process(data.Abstract.iloc[0])
```

I got it clean. But when I try a for, I got this

[image]

I tried already merging all the data from the column and then do the cleaning, with no luck (I don't know, I lost data).

Comment: Presumably you have some `NaN` in your column (missing data). This is technically of type float and this is not handled by your `pre_process` function.

Comment: Yup!! That's right!! that was the answer!!. So I got another question. How can i replace that NaN for, for another valor? like ""?

Comment: [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) -> `data.Abstract = data.Abstract.fillna('')` before processing. Or you could check `if np.isnan(value):` in the function.